# Apache rewrite any subdomain except one to non-www https

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to reduce the amount of 301 redirect chaining on my server so I'd like to combine a subdomain to non-www redirect (except where the subdomain is `dev`) with a HTTP to HTTPS redirect (using `%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}`) as the instance is behind a load balancer.

Here's what I have so far in my `.htaccess`:

```
# move http to https 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Remove leading www 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

There are three problems with my present implementation:

1. A request to `http://www.example.net` will have two redirects.
2. Like most www to non-www redirect examples on this site, it won't redirect `ww.` or `wwww.` so my analytics has lots of mistyped subdomains that haven't been redirected.
3. I'd like to exclude the `dev.` subdomain from redirection, so `http://dev.example.net` and its `https` sibling, as I use `dev.` for development and release staging.

How should I go about combining this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) A request to `http://www.example.net` will have two redirects.

This can be resolved by simply reversing the two rules. Then `www.example.net` is redirected to HTTPS in the first redirect, so the HTTP to HTTPS redirect does not need to trigger.

(This does, however, assume you have no intention of implementing [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) - in which case you would need to keep them as two redirects since redirecting to HTTPS on the same hostname *first* is a requirement.)

> 2) Like most www to non-www redirect examples on this site, it won't redirect `ww.` or `wwww.` so my analytics has lots of mistyped subdomains that haven't been redirected.

Ordinarily, requests to `ww.` or `wwww.` subdomains simply won't resolve, so this is not normally an issue. For this to work you have to have configured a *wildcard* subdomain in DNS and configured the server to accept such requests.

But this can be accounted for by modifying the regex (snippet) from `^www\.` to `^w{2,4}\.`.

> 3) I'd like to exclude the `dev.` subdomain from redirection, so `http://dev.example.net` and its `https` sibling, as I use `dev.` for development and release staging.

This only applies to the HTTP to HTTPS rule, so an additional condition can be applied here to exclude hostnames that start `dev.`.

Bringing the above points together, try the following:

```
# Remove leading ww, www or wwww (and redirect to HTTPS)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^w{2,4}\.example\.net [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.net/$1 [R=301,L]

# Move http to https (except dev subdomain)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} !^dev\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I've kept your use of `HTTP:Host` the same (in order to access the `Host` HTTP request header) in case this is a requirement of the load balancer? Otherwise, it's more common to use the `HTTP_HOST` server variable here.

The `!` prefix on the *CondPattern* (ie. `!^dev\.`) negates the regex, so the condition is successful when the `Host` does *not* start with `dev.`. (I assume `www.dev.` isn't a thing?)

`(.*)` is the same as `^(.*)$` since the regex is greedy by default.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing. It is advisable to first test with 302 (temporary) redirects in order to avoid any caching issues.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Remove leading www, always using https regardless of the current URL scheme
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^w{2,4}.example.net(?::|$) [NC,NV]
RewriteRule .* https://example.net%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# move http to https, except for dev.example.net
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http [NC,NV]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev.example.net(?::|$) [NC,NV]
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

1. Added `NC` (`nocase`) flag to the `X-Forwarded-Proto` condition, since its value seemed to be case-insignificant i.e. `HTTP = Http = hTTp = http`. You're free to remove this.
2. Added `NV` (`novary`) flag to the `X-Forwarded-Proto` condition to hide it from the `Vary` response header. Again, you're free to remove this especially if it is not the case (the reverse proxy automatically filters it for you anyway before sending it to client) or needed for correct cacheing behaviour (the cache does not otherwise distinguish `http` and `https` content).
3. Added `NV` (`novary`) flag to the `Host` header condition to hide it from the `Vary` response header. You may also remove this if you have a broken cache server.
4. Made the `RewriteRule` flag order consistent (`L,R=301` and `R=301,L` are essentially the same).
5. Prevented `www.example.net.but.not.actually.yours.com` from being recognized, but still allows e.g. `www.example.net:443`.
6. Consistently use `%{REQUEST_URI}` as the substitution.
7. Also recognize `ww` and `wwww`.